# Rust orphan rule and From trait

Tags: rust

From [Rustbook chapter on Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type)

> But **we can’t implement external traits on external types**. For example,
> we can’t implement the Display trait on Vec within our aggregator
> crate, because Display and Vec are both defined in the standard
> library and aren’t local to our aggregator crate. This restriction is
> part of a property called coherence, and more specifically the orphan
> rule, so named because the parent type is not present.

Reading the above, I expected that it wouldn't be possible to implement external trait [`std::convert::From`](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/convert/trait.From.html) on external type [`std::vec::Vec`](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

To my huge surprise, I was wrong. The following code actually works:

```
impl From<MyType> for Vec<usize> {
    fn from(my_type: MyType) -> Self {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So, what are the actual orphan rules?

Comment: Is that meant to be `... for Vec<MyType>`? Don't think you can implement things for ungeneric generic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What allows this is that you have a generic trait and `MyType` is a local type.

You can find the complete [orphan rules in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence):

> Given `impl<P1..=Pn> Trait<T1..=Tn> for T0`, an impl is valid only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - […]
> - All of
>
>   - At least one of the types `T0..=Tn` must be a [local type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#local-type). Let `Ti` be the first such type.
>   - No [uncovered type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) parameters `P1..=Pn` may appear in `T0..Ti` (excluding `Ti`)

Comment: "No uncovered type parameters" - what does uncovered mean in this context?

Comment: Same as everywhere in the reference, I've added the links that got lost when I copy & pasted.